# right click and generate truecrypt volume from contents

Tags: encryption, truecrypt, shell-extensions

has any one found a way to take the contents of a folder and programiticly generate a volume for it in truecrypt that is just the right size?

like in windows how you right click and select send to archive etc...  I am hoping theres a solution for linux to either gather the relevent data or script a command line to generate the volume and copy or move contents to that volume.

Comment: This would require you intergrate Truecrypt into the Windows shell, hard to do, without a great deal of programming experience

Comment: @Ramhound I'm sure comment still holds but OP is asking for a Linux solution " I am hoping theres a solution for linux"

Answer (score 0):

Does it *have* to be a truecrypt container, or a container at all?

- If you'd like [gpg](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GnuPG) (pgp), then

  tar -z -cv datadir | gpg --output data.tar.gz.gpg -c

  creates a passphrase (as opposed to `-e` public/secret key) encrypted compressed tar file, about the *same size* or maybe *smaller* than the source folder.
- **[eCryptFS](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ECryptfs)** or **[EncFS](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/EncFS)** would do on-the-fly encryption of a new folder, that's about the same size as the original.

  - Does not use a container file or partition, keeps encrypted files on the same drive in a new folder. Therefore only uses as much disk space as is required (after encryption some files are a little larger, tiny files may have a minimum size) and increases in size dynamically (ex. space is only limited by the host filesystem).
- [TrueCrypt](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/TrueCrypt) still exists for Linux, not officially supported anymore but it's not "broken" or anything AFAIK (as of the start of 2016). But cryptsetup below supports the truecrypt format & existing volumes too...
- [dm-crypt / cryptsetup / LUKS](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dm-crypt) uses container files that look like a separate partition/drive, very similar to truecrypt.
- A custom script (bash for instance) you create with a combination of `du -bs <folder> | cut -f1` to find the required size and creating a file of the size plus the dm-crypt/LUKS & filesystem overhead space (varies by encryption type, # of keys, filesystem type & options) could work too, and **dm-crypt/cryptsetup supports truecrypt volumes** too.

Comment: I would be expecting it to do strong encryption for things including tax records. I would prefer a fs level approach where i can mount a drive of the requested data. if i need to update it i just create a new larger container with the new data.

Comment: The tools I listed all do those, with the "folder only" eCryptFS & EncFS advantages of not wasting space with the empty parts of a "container" and you never have to create a larger "container". But using linux, and especially **bash**, you can do almost anything you want, just write your own script so it's exactly how you like it, you won't be happy or *fully trust it* unless you do. I'll add some help / FAQ links to the tools in the answer, and definitely see [arch's Disk Encryption](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Disk_encryption) overview & info, top notch